# Magento: get a static block as html in a phtml file

Tags: php, magento

I have a static block called `newest_product` (with content) and I would like to display it on a `.phtml` file as <kbd>html</kbd>.

I've tried this code:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('newest_product')->toHtml();
```

But this nothing is being displayed.

Am I using the wrong code?

Comment: did you refresh the cache? code seams to be correct

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In the layout (app/design/frontend/your_theme/layout/default.xml):

```
<default>
    <cms_page> <!-- need to be redefined for your needs -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="cms/block" name="cms_newest_product" as="cms_newest_product">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>newest_product</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_page>
</default>
```

In your phtml template:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newest_product'); ?>
```

Don't forget about cache cleaning.

I think it help.

Comment: Any workaround to get title of Child CMS block? I can fetch title through php but I have no idea how to get title of block that is loaded by layout xml.. TIA

Comment: Don't forget it's typically better to use a local.xml in your layout theme instead of overriding individual xml files.

Comment: "What is <cms_page> redefined to to suit my needs???" - it means that you need to change this handle to the one that you are using. 

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html

Comment: I believe you can just use the value after 'as' for a parameter of getChildHtml(). Adding the "<action method="" ... </action>"-line isn't necessary.

Answer (score 78):

If you have created CMS block named 'block_identifier' from admin panel.
Then following will be code to call them in .phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); 
?>
```

Comment: I like this approach more than the one @Mcs mentioned. Using layout is most of the times messy

Comment: Like it also. And more simple than the __Mage::getModel('cms/block')__ method, which also works

Comment: @karantan setting ID in phtml file is basically hard-codding it in the template. Layouts represents configuration part of a system where id is expected to be used. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 21):

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my_static_block_name')->toHtml() ?>
```

and use this link for more
http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/how-to-call-static-block-in-magento/

Answer (score 14):

If you want to load a cmsblock into your template/blockfile/model etc. You can do this as followed. This will render any variables places in the cmsblock

```
$block  = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load('identifier');

$var = array('variable' => 'value', 'other_variable' => 'other value');
/* This will be {{var variable}} and {{var other_variable}} in your CMS block */

$filterModel = Mage::getModel('cms/template_filter');
$filterModel->setVariables($var);

echo $filterModel->filter($block->getContent());
```

Comment: This is the only way to get your block to display from a .phtml file including variables in the cms block without the use of XML and `getChildHtml()`. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I think this will work for you

```
$block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load('newest_product');
echo $block->getTitle();
echo $block->getContent();
```

It does work but now the variables in CMS block are not parsing anymore :(

Comment: This will not take any images uploaded via editor in cms block

Answer (score 5):

Following code will work when you Call CMS-Static Block in Magento.

```
<?php echo 

$this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();

?>
```

Comment: This is the same answer that was posted earlier.

Answer (score 2):

This should work as tested.

```
<?php
$filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
$_widget = $filter->filter('{{widget type="cms/widget_page_link" template="cms/widget/link/link_block.phtml" page_id="2"}}');
echo $_widget;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new CMS block named *block_identifier* from the admin panel you can use the following code to call it from your .phtml file:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); 
?>
```

Then clear the cache and reload your browser.